# CSS animations not working when i pass variables through HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with animations when I pass variables through HTML. My code is :

```css
.falling-star {
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  position: absolute;
  animation: falling-star-animation var(--animationTime) infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes falling-star-animation {
  40% {
    top: var(--top);
    left: var(--left);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  60% {
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    top: var(--endTop);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    left: var(--endLeft);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="falling-star" style="--top:2vh; --endTop:90vh; --left:50vw; --endLeft:10vw; --animationTime:8s; --animationDelay: 2s;"></div>
<div class="falling-star" style="--top:4vh; --endTop:70vh; --left:90vw; --endLeft:50vw; --animationTime:4s; --animationDelay: .5s;"></div>
<div class="falling-star" style="--top:0; --endTop:50vh; --left:88vw; --endLeft:30vw; --animationTime:3s; --animationDelay: 1s;"></div>
```

I thought that animations are behind something (lower z-index), but they aren't. When I inspect them in console, then I see that they aren't moving. When I change from variables to static values then the animation is working. Earlier it was working but I probably changed something by accident and I don't know what's this (git history doesn't show any changes in this code).

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: Yeah, the code snippet works fine on the preview. I would recommend though using "transform: translate()" to animate for better performance, rather than top and left

Comment: Hmm, not in my code, is it possible that angular is disabling this animation?

Comment: I updated page with example, where its not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i debuged this. Resolve was to remove camel case and type every css variable using only lower case. I don't know why it works like that, but for everyone who will come here in future - this is my solution of this problem :D